# Calculate isochrones in R within a personal network

Tags: r, distance, isochrone, travelling-salesman

I just need to calculate the isochrones in R from an starting point within a personal network. This network is a sf linestring with an id attribute and a speed value. There are not any other restrictions. Just that.

I've already tryed `osmr` and `dodgr` libraries, but I thing they just work somehow with the data from OSM.

To complicate things, points are not connected to the network, so an extra direct line to the network should be included. This connections can be straight lines and should have the value of SPEED of the connected line.

[image]

[DOWNLOAD THE DATA TO TRYOUT](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1gJGiZWDW-bRBDr65WcPsir7dmSLMy4Ij?usp=sharing)